# Closing composer using PyQt5

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt5, composer-manager

Migrating from 2.8 to 3.4 i stumble on what seems a simple task: closing programmaticaly an opened composer. To open it is no trouble with the layout manager but to close it is another story. the composeurWindow() method is nowhere to be found (or the equivalent).

Comment: The feature that was called a "Print Composer" in QGIS 2.x is now called a "Print Layout" in 3.x. If the solution isn't as simple as substituting the word "layout" for "composer," at least you should be able to find the right section in the new PyQGIS cookbook. https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/

Comment: Nope, not to be found (as the answer to the same question with PyQt4 was not to be found also).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open and close layouts programmatically in QGIS 3.4, you could use something like this:

Open a layout by name:

```
layout_name = 'Test'
layout = QgsProject().instance().layoutManager().layoutByName(layout_name)
iface.openLayoutDesigner(layout)
```

Then closing the layout is as simple as:

```
iface.openLayoutDesigners()[0].close()
```

To close a layout by its name:

```
for x in iface.openLayoutDesigners():
    if x.layout().name() == 'Test':
        x.close()
```

Or close all open layouts:

```
for x in iface.openLayoutDesigners():
    x.close()
```

Tested in QGIS 3.4